# How to add Android App UI CSS for Android App in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, material-design

I need to know that I have weather App and UI for this Weather App in CSS, Psd etc. My query is how can I add this UI (Psd/CSS) with my Weather App in Android Studio. If anyone know please show me step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Psd is not gonna work. You have to 'translate' this in a XML file in order to view in Android Studio... another way is just transform the psd in pngs and jpegs file (only for views, to edit you should separate all graphical componentes). 
Css is other thing, other way. You can use Css in a WebView component, the main reference to guide is: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can please suggest how to convert Psd to XML i.e. software or tools to convert it. Specify or suggest me for conversation of Psd to XML.

Comment: You can begin here: http://exportkit.com/learn/how-to/export-your-psd/convert-a-psd-to-android-xml-ui-and-java